I'm running a Windows 10 desktop and would like to be able to create a bootable thumbdrive so that I can move files on or off of it
I began periodically imaging my system partition in the late 90's when Windows (98) was less reliable. With every system crash, I'd have to spend an entire afternoon reformatting the drive, re-installing the OS and applications, and resetting my shortcuts, preferences, defaults, etc.  So I finally found some software that used its own OS to allow me to image my system drive, create a bootable CD, then put the image and the recovery software on the CD.  That way if my system got trashed, I just booted to the CD, restored my drive, and was up and running in 10 minutes, smiling.  The CD was "permanent" media so it was virtually impossible for those files to to be corrupted or lost - it was great!  I had a way to recover (or repair) my Windows drive without depending on Windows for the recovery.
Well, that great software finally stopped working with one of my Windows upgrades (Vista??). About the same time, my drive images got too large to be stored on CDs, even with compression.  As a workaround, I added a second physical HD in place of a CD and used alternative imaging software, which actually worked fine, and I highly recommend two or more hard drives (SSDs) in a desktop computer (I have five currently).
HOWEVER, I don't want to rely solely on SSDs for drive recovery and would like to regain the ability to restore from removable media (e.g. USB thumb drive).  I see lots of web sites purporting to show how to make "bootable USB drives" or "how to put Windows on a thumb drive" but they usually just turn out to refer to setting up the familiar Windows "Media Creation Tool."  The resulting thumb drives don't contain "Windows" nor any other OS that can run recovery software nor the ability to add files.
Does anyone know of a way to create a bootable removable media that can handle adding a system image and imaging software?

You may want to look into Veeam. They have a free backup solution where you backup your entire pc to a removable drive, and they allow you to create a recovery CD. If your PC does not boot anymore, you boot from the CD to restore the last backup.

Windows natively supports imaging partitions via Dism (Windows XP ≤ 7: ImageX), and I cover this in-depth here. A secondary boot medium isn't required since the OS partition can be imaged from WinRE: Shutdown /f /r /o /t 0 (Once booted to WinRE: Advanced → Troubleshoot → Command Prompt). WinPE, Windows, and WinRE all come by default with Dism and ImageX - if wanting to build a custom WinRE environment to boot to (WinRE is WinPE with additional WinPE OCs specific to recovery), see this answer.

Yes, I agree wholeheartedly that having a verified full drive image is essential. Two ways to do this:

Make a bootable image of the actual drive, such as with Hasleo's WinToUSB.
Make a bootable device to image the drive to external media, and to restore it from media.

Though the first option might seem simpler, there are serious issues with it:

Booting the image requires identical hardware.
Bootable OS images may be incredibly s l o w.
Though one can run from the USB, it often cannot be restored to the internal drive.

The second, I find, is the better option. There are a number of tools to make a bootable USB, CD or DVD, which can be used to make a disk image and to restore the image to the original drive. Some of these use an operating system (OS) such as Windows PE or Windows RE, or a version of Linux, such as Knoppix,  which are designed to boot rapidly on most PC's.
Be aware that tools are either for 32-bit or 64-bit machine architecture! For example, Macrium Reflect Free can be installed in either 32-bit or 64-bit version.

If your old utility no longer works, perhaps on a new PC, then try a newer one, such as Reflect or one of the many free and commercial alternatives.
To do as you ask, "to restore from removable media (e.g. USB thumb drive),"

Download imaging software and install it -- either on the PC to be imaged, or even another PC.
Create the "rescue media" on USB or other media, using that utility. For example, With Reflect, create Macrium Rescue Environment, for DriveImage XML, create a Runtime Live CD or USB Stick.
Make an image of the internal drive to external media. One can use a flash USB drive, external hard disk drive (HDD), external solid state drive (SSD), DVD, etc. For long-term storage when not plugged in, the external HDD is my choice. If you've created an extra partition on the rescue media, the image could be stored there, but I prefer to keep boot media and multiple images separate.
The image can be restored to the PC by booting from the rescue media, and then moving the image back to the internal drive.
Most of these utilities also allow access to files and folders within the image, so some data or specific apps can be restored without having to restore the whole image.

